# Too many engineers in the caboose

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

One of my bosses mentioned this phrase the other day:

> Too many engineers in the caboose

I discovered the meaning of *caboose* today (Fourgon-frein), but for some reason searching for the phrase on Google does not yield results.

I like the phrase but I am wondering if it is totally made up or if it is derived from something else.

Can any native English speakers comment on the phrase?

Comment: I've never heard it myself. I would take it to be roughly equivalent to "too many backseat drivers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caboose)
> *Caboose*:
> a freight-train car attached usually to the rear mainly for the use of the train crew

If there are too many engineers (the crew) in the caboose it becomes uncomfortable and decisions about the working of the train involve too many people. This leads to delay, uncertainty, divided opinion and inefficiency.

So the phrase refers to the confusion of having too many people to do a job well.

A related English proverb is “Too many cooks spoil the broth”.

> [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+many+cooks+spoil+the+broth)
> *too many cooks spoil the broth*, proverb:
> If too many people try to control, influence, or work on something, the final product will be worse as a result.

Comment: You are assuming here that the operative part of the phrase is *too many* and that *engineers* is used to mean simply the crew. An engineer, in American English, is however, someone who is supposed to be in the engine, so if there were too may engineers in the caboose, the problem would be not only their number, but also their being in the wrong place. That seems relevant to what somebody might intend to convey by using this phrase metaphorically, although it is, of course, difficult to be sure about that, as it is not an established part of the language.

Comment: @jsw you are correct about my assumption, and I am grateful for the elaboration of my answer. Thanks.